# .htaccess URL rewrite rules folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this in my html folder

```
--html
  --.htaccess
  --app
      --application_name
        --public
          --index.php
  --landing_page
    --index.php
```

As of now, everytime the website url is accessed (www.website.com), the browser opens the landing_page/index.php.

How can I make it that when I access www.website.com/beta, I will be doing a request to html/app/application_name/public/index.php

I have tried adding this to the .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^beta/?$ app/application_name/public/index.php [L,NC]
```

This is the whole .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^beta/?$ app/application_name/public/index.php [L,NC]
```

But it does not work. Not sure what term to use to search for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your root is currently set at /html, and therefore the `RewriteBase /` is at `/`, the `/beta/` simply does not exist. You could change the `RewriteBase /app/application_home/public/` and set the `RewriteRule ^beta/?$ index.php [L,NC]`. This however no longer give you the access to the landing page, not sure if this is what you want?

Comment: I need the landing page still though

Comment: Then create a separate .htaccess within the `/app/application_home/public/` directory, with the `RewriteBase /app/application_home/public/`, and the rewrite rule as `RewriteRule ^beta/?$ index.php [L,NC]`

Comment: What is the complete .htaccess?

Comment: The complet .htacess is similar to your .htaccess, just change those lines that I mentioned but put in the directory that you'd want to have the rewrite